# GitHub: Go back to a previous version and branch it

Tags: git, github, version-control, revision

Is it possible to go back to a previous revision and then branch it without affecting the current master version.

A quick backstory:

We updated a template for a company website that have a more robust navigation. Turn out they can't afford the new changes and just want to update their current navigations css.

Right now I'm 10+ version/commit ahead of the old navigation. So I'm wondering if it's possible to work on that version and just create a branch from that point on.

Kinda like this:

```
                 "new" old version branch
               /
(init) --- old version --- current version
```

This way if  the company ever do want to update it to the new navigation I can just continue it from the current master version.

Sorry if this sounds confusing, not familiar with version controls terms

Comment: Sure. `git checkout -b newBranch oldCommitHashOrBranchName`.

Comment: And you can find the commit hash either with `git log` or on github. It's the really long string with letters and numbers, but you only need the first few characters (the first 8 or so)

Comment: @JBNizet It worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with:

```
git checkout <old_version_commit_hash>
git checkout -b "<new_old_version_branch_name>"
```